# Can you create a TextureAtlas from inside a libgdx program?

Tags: java, libgdx, texture-atlas

I my game I'm letting the user customize a character from a wide variety of sprites, I want to create a final texture atlas including the selected sprites to use in game instead of loading the big texture atlas with all other useless sprites and only using the necessary sprites.

I think I have to run some sort of command, but I don't know which...

Thanks!

Comment: hey,

you could use [andengine](http://www.andengine.org/). it's provide what you want: 
BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas - load and unload functions + adding Texture_region

and then you can load this textures, when you need them.

Comment: Not really what I wanted though, I'm using libgdx and don't want to change engine just because of this. Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: You need to add the gdx-tools dependency to your game. It has the `TexturePacker` class to do what you want. lol @andengine...